# bootstrap multiselect on refresh creates new multiselect element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am cloning rows in my input form and in this row there are multiple multiselect elements.

After only cloning and setting the values to the same as in previous row the multiselect elements are not working, so i have to use 'refresh' option, but this creates a new multiselect element

my code

```
    $($row[last]).after($newRow);
    var multiselectValuesW =  ($('.multiselectWorkers',$row[last]).val());
    $('.multiselectWorkers', $newRow).val(multiselectValuesW);
    $('.multiselectWorkers',$newRow).multiselect('refresh');
```

Any suggestion?? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you need ajax. You can do what you try do without reloading, only what you need is write function to copy value after when you do something e.g. when you click on a checkbox.

Comment: I am not reloading. Copying or cloning works fine but on refresh a new multiselect element is added. Why? I create new row with var $newRow = $($row[last]).clone();